# No more constrain on bitmap resolution in Flash Player 11?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, resolution, bitmapdata, flash-player-11

Feature set over [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/features.html) claims that:

> Enable the development of apps
>   that use very large bitmaps. BitmapData objects are no longer limited
>   to a maximum resolution of 16 megapixels (16,777,215 pixels), and
>   maximum bitmap width/height is no longer limited to 8,191 pixels.

Does this mean that limit does not exist anymore, or it just has been raised to a greater value (as it used to be in previous versions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just limited by RAM you have (available for FlashPlayer).

Comment: Has it been noted somewhere or it is your wild guess?

Comment: Definitely was noted somewhere, but can't remember exactly. Most probably Thibault Imbert (FP project manager) mentioned in some report (AdobeMAX most probably). But you can always try test yourself if have any doubts)