# Flash player 11 - size limit of bitmap data dependant on OS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

[According to docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html)

> Starting with AIR 3 and Flash player 11, the size limits for a
>   BitmapData object have been removed. The maximum size of a bitmap is
>   now dependent on the operating system.

I am following up on question to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277639/no-more-constrain-on-bitmap-resolution-in-flash-player-11?rq=1).

It would be nice to *get the largest bitmap that OS would permit*.

Can I check the RAM available and pick bitmap size accordingly? Or do I need to pick a size like 4096x4096 and stick to it?

**update:** trying the following: `new BitmapData(4096, 4096, transp, 0x00FFFFFF);` 
Gives me error - `Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData.`  It looks like I'm hitting Flash Player 10 ceiling of 16,777,215 pixels even though I'm compiling and running 11.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a while( true ) where you create new BitmapDatas of the shape new BitmapData( 1, x );

You see, the limit is actually the bitmapdata's width * height, so just increase x ! Don't start from 1, start from 16 million or something. Afterwards you have your width * height limit, which most likely is Y squared. Just do a Math.sqrt( x ) and you will have your limit, assuming you are interested in squares. Otherwise determine a width and your max height will be x / width, rounded down.

Comment: It's maxing out at 4096 x 4095, after that if I increase it to 4096 x 4096 I get that error.

Comment: Then you have your limit right there. on your particular OS on that particular flash player / swf version.